# Apply function only to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, parent

I am learning jQuery and I am using the Javascript code from: http://jsfiddle.net/MUsT8

In another question I asked how to translate something to jQuery to be able to use classes and user Pointy solved my question with:

```
var rgb = getAverageRGB($('.first_img')[0]);
$('.post').css("background-color", 'rgb('+rgb.r+','+rgb.g+','+rgb.b+')');
```

But there is a problem with that and is that it adds the background color to all the 'post' classes when I only want it for the parent post the image is in. My Html is like follows.

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="circle">
        <img class="first_img" id="try" src="./img/train.jpg" height="100%">
    </div>
    <h2 class="title">
        The big Lebowski
    </h2>
</div>
```

and my intent to make the jQuery work is like this:

```
var rgb = getAverageRGB($('.first_img')[0]);
$(this).parent().parent().css("background-color", 'rgb('+rgb.r+','+rgb.g+','+rgb.b+')');
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need jQuery to select by class, if that's what you meant by *"to be able to use classes"*.

Comment: How could you do that in jQuery, I havent found a way.

Comment: You mean without jQuery? `document.querySelectorAll(".post")`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `$(this)` to refer to each `.first_img` in turn, you’ll need to iterate through them:

```
$('.first_img').each(function () {
    var rgb = getAverageRGB(this);
    $(this).closest('.post').css("background-color", 'rgb('+rgb.r+','+rgb.g+','+rgb.b+')');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

So reference the element and get the parent that way

```
var img = $('.first_img').eq(0);
var rgb = getAverageRGB(img[0]);
img.parent().parent().css("background-color", 'rgb('+rgb.r+','+rgb.g+','+rgb.b+')');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `closest`, it's exactly for what you need.

Like:

```
$(this).closest('.post').css(...)
```

Details in jQuery doc.